# PHP-generated user gallery pics as background-image in external css

Tags: php, css, background-image

All of my CSS styling is done with an external stylesheet, but I have a php-generated gallery of user photos that requires a background-image for a div that is the user's picture (as the variable $userpic below). There is no problem with this using inline css:

```
echo "<div style=\"width:100px;height:110px;z-index:1;background-   
image:URL('$userpic');background-size:100px 110px;background-repeat:no-repeat;\">
</div>";
```

but is there a way move the styling elements of the echoed div (class "NoPicDiv") below into the external stylesheet, perhaps something like the following?

```
echo "<div class=\"NoPicDiv\"></div>"//modified php echo statement

/*The following would be in my external css file*/
.NoPicDiv {
width:100px;
height:110px;
z-index:1;
background-image:URL('$userpic');
background-size:100px 110px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Worst case scenario I move all the styling elements to the stylesheet except the background-image element and just keep this inline. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think the best solution is to do exactly what you said, just make the background part inline and the rest in style sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option…

**A)** generate a second, smaller CSS file via PHP, which only contains the `background-image` properties;

**B)** write the image URLs either inline to the tag or at the end of the body

The question here is, why do you need background images at all and not just output `<img>` tags. Background images won't get indexed by search engines and you can't store a title to them. If you are handling photos, you should definitely use IMG tags.

Comment: There is additional code (not shown) in the echo statement that generates many additional z-index layers.....setting userpic as background-image was best way to go for me.

Comment: Are you using a mysql database  or a php framework at all ? Because that would a make this a whole lot easier what are you drawing your user data from ?